# Unable to scan for Bluetooth devices using Flutter Blue in some Android devices

Tags: flutter, permissions, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions

I am developing a Flutter application that uses the Flutter Blue package for Bluetooth communication. I am encountering an issue where the Bluetooth scanning functionality does not work on some Android devices. The application fails to scan for Bluetooth devices, and I receive the following error message:

`Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(startScan, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource, java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource: GattService registerScanner`

I have already included the necessary permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file as follows:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

I have also ensured that the required features are added:
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />`

Despite including these permissions, the scanning functionality works on some Android devices but fails on others. I have tested on multiple devices, and the issue seems to be device-specific rather than a problem with my code.

I have also tried requesting Bluetooth permissions at runtime using the permission_handler package, but the issue persists.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem and successfully scan for Bluetooth devices using the Flutter Blue package on all Android devices. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Since a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing in your question, here are some general tips. Since you have tested on several devices, make a list of which devices your software works on and which do not. Find out if there is a pattern regarding the version of Android running there.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) you can find the Google developer documentation on Bluetooth permission in different Android versions.

Comment: The error message is clear: you are missing the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission

Comment: What's the difference between the working and non working Android devices? Does the Android version differ? Keep in mind that `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` is a runtime permission, you need to [request it at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)